# Convergence of sequence in a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, linear-transformations

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space of dimension $d$ and $\alpha$,  $\beta$ : $V \to \mathbb R^d$ are two vector space isomorphisms .

If $v_n$ is a sequence in $V$ , then $\alpha(v_n)$ converges to $\alpha(v)$ iff $\beta(v_n)$ converges to $\beta(v)$.

$\mathbf {My \ approach}:$  Actually , I was trying to link the matrices of $\alpha$ and  $\beta$ (matrix under some fixed ordered basis of $V$), but I couldn't do anything .

A small hint is greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The linear map $\beta \circ \alpha^{-1}: \Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R^d$ is linear and therefore continuous.